# Always cascade CSS background-color

Tags: css, background-color

Can't get the background color to always cascade:  http://jsfiddle.net/yHgTt/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      td { background-color: blue; } 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="background-color: yellow">
      yellow
      <span>
        and yellow too
      </span>
    </div>
    <span style="background-color: yellow !important ">
      yellow
      <div>
        not yellow but expecting to be
      </div>
    </span>
    <table>
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color: yellow !important">
          <td>
            expecting to be yellow
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

Use case is highlighting parts of a third party site using a chrome extension.  Whilst I can manipulate the html I do not want to do this at all so that the highlighting/annotating is as easy and error free as possible.

Comment: What do you mean by... cascade? Do you mean inherit? If so, why do you need the background to inherit?

Comment: First of all: your HTML is invalid: `<div>` cannot be placee inside `<span>` ...

Comment: I would highly recommend against your second edit.  There is a reason why background properties don't inherit by default.  If anything, I would target your specific cases a little more careful (i.e. `td {background-color: inherit;}`) rather than a blanket global change of all elements

Comment: @steve please see edit 1 for use case,  don't really mind messing up other colours on the page as long as mine gets through.... though granted it doesn't seem like this would actually work.

Comment: @AJP - Well, if that is your use case, then do whatever you want.  But it is bad practice to use a sledge hammer on a push pin.  The question in general is quite good, but if you are only concerned about your specific use case, I would vote to close this question as too localized.  If somebody reads this in the future, they might get the wrong impression on how to actually deal with this problem correctly.

Comment: @steve, I agree.  And in this case the sledgehammer doesn't work so I'll remove my edit 2 of `<style>body * { background-color: inherit; }</style>` so it doesn't confuse future viewers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`background-color` does not get inherited!

> Background properties are not inherited, but the parent box's
>   background will shine through by default because of the initial
>   'transparent' value on 'background-color'.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#background

However, nested element that do not have a background color might show the background color of the element behind it.

So for your cases:

- The first example works, because the inner span doesn't have a background color and the background of the div shines through.
- The second example doesn't work, because only the `<span>` (inline element) portion gets the background color, but doesn't wrap the nested `<div>` (block element).
- The third example doesn't work, because the `<td>` has its own background color and therefore nothing shines through

Comment: Steve, `<style>* { background-color: inherit; }</style>` does work in chrome for the span -> div issue, perhaps a bug in their implementation of css?  Thanks for the quote and the link, looks like I'll have to recurse down through the elements I want to highlight and apply the style to each one, which is annoying.  I wish background properties were inherited.

Comment: @AJP - You might want to read up on the use of `!important` in CSS.  Of course `<style>* { background-color: inherit; }</style>` won't work in your example, because it will never overcome the `style="background-color: yellow !important"`.  But again, even if you get it to work, I still believe that approach is inherently wrong. :)

Comment: @AJP: Not a bug. The spec is not clear on this but what it means is that backgrounds aren't inherited *by default* - you can still force them to inherit using `inherit`, but given the nature of backgrounds doing so is generally never a good idea.

Comment: @steve, sorry that should have read `<style>body * { background-color: inherit; }</style>` which does not "over come" but does allow the div to get the background-color of the parent span.  I think we agree on it being the wrong approach in both this specific use case and definitely in general.

Answer (score 0):

<span> cannot contain <div>.  Most likely the browser is "correcting" this for you by placing the <div> after the <span>, where your CSS rule would not apply.

if you change <span> to <div> your example works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues.

1. You have a `<div>` tag inside of a `<span>` tag, which is not correct.
2. Your CSS is `td { background-color: #8AE; }`, but you're applying a yellow background color to the `<tr>` tag, which is a parent of the `<td>`.

I've updated your CSS to this:

```
tr { background-color: #8AE; }
```

And your HTML to this:

```
<body>
    <div style="background-color: yellow">
        yellow <span>and yellow too</span>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: yellow !important ">
        yellow <span>not yellow but expecting to be</span>
    </div>
    <table>
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color: yellow !important">
          <td> expecting to be yellow </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

You can see it works as intended here: http://jsfiddle.net/yHgTt/2/